# Making the points always visible in a flex line chart

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, adobe, visualization

I'm trying to do something very similar to this example (source code enabled):

http://www.sunild.com/proto/line_chart_example.html

When you hover over each data point, a circle appears indicating that this is a point. How do I keep those circles visible at all times?

**Edit: this example isn't mine, but you can view the source enabled here:**

http://www.sunild.com/proto/line_chart_example_src/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Umm, the case you show is a working example giving no details about the code itself. There are enormous ways the code could be. 
For Eg - The code could be keeping an event listener over & out a mouse event...So removing it pretty much keeps the circles there. 
But still I suggest show at least what you are doing, if not that code to get some clue.

Comment: Hmm....Well it pretty much explains I guess.
http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/charts/LineChart.html
Its a custom made part by adobe & I don't think you can directly customize it as per your needs.

Comment: FYI, they come with a set of options you can turn on or off. That's what my question is about.